# Unable to use git in Android Studio : Error updating changes: unsafe repository ... is owned by someone else

Tags: git, android-studio

I am getting the following error when I try to access git from my Android studio. I am able to do git operations using terminal

> Error:fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/....' is owned by someone else)
> To add an exception for this directory, call:
> git config --global --add safe.directory /home/....

I already tried git config --global --add safe.directory /home/.... but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason running the command in Android studio's terminal worked although running it through the normal terminal didn't help

> git config --global --add safe.directory /home/....